# What if an answer is good but not completely usable?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

I asked a question that got a pretty good answer.  But the answer requires me to change something in my preamble where I only want to make a one-time change within a single list.  (This involves the enumitem package.)  I put a comment on the answer asking how to get the local fix (it's not obvious to me how to do it, and I don't understand the enumitem documentation very well).  How do I know if the original answerer has seen my comment?  What I I do if he never responds to my comment?  Do I ask the question again, specifically stating that I know about the putting-it-in-the-preamble solution?  Do I edit my original question?  Should I give the original answerer a chance to respond to my comment?  What's the best practice here?

And here's a meta-meta question: should I give specific detail about my question and its answer here in this meta question?  Or would that just be distracting?

Comment: Do you mean this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277235/how-do-i-put-subscripts-on-referenced-items-with-enumitem? You asked it about two hours ago -- it's quite natural that there's no immediate response

Comment: Have you ever answered a question, looked on your watch and thought "oh, i'm late" and hurried out of the house?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer  Really, this wasn't meant to be critical of anybody.  You can tell because I asked it *right* after I posted the comment.  Obviously I wouldn't expect someone to respond within two minutes. So I guess I didn't phrase my question well.  I just wanted to know how and when people get notified if there's a comment on their post or a comment on their comment.  I asked because I thought I'd written at-user.  But I must have accidentally deleted it at the last second because it didn't show up in my comment.  So I didn't know whether he'd be notified of it anyway.

Comment: @Ruby: I think cfr will see it, if not, leave a notice here and I will write to her

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interestingly you ask about non-responding users concerning their answers -- the opposite about people requesting something in their questions and never react on comments or give any kind of feedback to answers is far more frequent and my impression is that this a growing 'feature' unfortunately.

Any user that answered a question will see the comments below his or her answer in his inbox or in the `responses` menu.

A bunch of users are quite active here and get a lot of comments as responses -- it might take a while until the user will respond too.

The particular question and answer(s) to it is in general no topic for Meta.SX unless in very special cases about style or spam or has offending content (but even then it's more of a moderator issue)

I think the user will address your request, just give some grace period -- users go to sleep after some time ;-)

Another possibility: Ask the user in the TeX.SX chat about the answer.

Comment: Where is the responses menu?

Comment: I really wasn't considering this a case of a non-responding user.  But I can see how my phrasing could make it come across as if I were.  I'll be more careful in the future about how my wording might come across, since everyone is so nice and helpful here.

Comment: @Ruby: responses menu: I meant the bar with `summary answers ... responses` etc.